# OS X Messages AppleScript handler: save images?

Tags: applescript, imessage

I've been attempting to use AppleScript to save incoming messages on an Apple Messages account, like so:

```
on active chat message received theMessage from theBuddy
    set theFileID to open for access POSIX file "/Users/me/Desktop/test" with write permission
    write theMessage to theFileID
    close access theFileID
    return theMessage
end active chat message received
```

which works great for text messages, but if the user sends an image the message appears to just be an empty string. Is there any way to fetch this image, or - as I fear - is it not accessible?

Comment: as far as I know images are treated as `file transfer` and saved automatically. There is another event handler which is called when the file transfer is complete providing the path and other properties.

Comment: I tried listening to the "completed file transfer" but it was never fired. In the mean time I've discovered that Messages uses SQLite as a data backend, so I'm just using that (not applicable for everyone, however)

Comment: Try listening on 'received file transfer invitation' instead to see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer, but I've discovered that the OS X Messages app uses SQLite for storage, at `~/Library/Messages/chat.db`. It has a table named `attachment` which lists the filenames of all attachments.

For my purposes, this is enough - but I'd love to hear if there are more legitimate alternatives.